# output of map function?

Tags: scheme, racket, brackets

Hi I am trying to understand the output of the following code

```
(define p (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (x (x y)))))
(define q (lambda (x) (* x x)))
```

when I use

```
(map (p q) (list 1 2 3))
```

the result is

```
(1 16 81)
```

shouldn't the answer be

```
(1 4 9) ?
```

Comment: `(map q (list 1 2 3))` would certainly return that. But `(p q)` is different from `q`, so you get different results. Try to work out what `(p q)` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mapping `(p q)` over the list, so start with figuring out what that is.

Using the subsitution method, you get

```
    (p q)
==> ((lambda (x) (lambda (y) (x (x y)))) q)
==> (lambda (y) (q (q y)))
==> (lambda (y) (q ((lambda (x) (* x x)) y)))
==> (lambda (y) (q (* y y)))
==> (lambda (y) ((lambda (x) (* x x)) (* y y)))
==> (lambda (y) (* (* y y) (* y y)))
```

so `(p q)` is a function that takes a number and squares its square.

Answer (score 0):

Two functions are provided:

```
(define p (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (x (x y)))))
(define q (lambda (x) (* x x)))
```

`q` is a function which takes a number and squares it.
`p` is a function which takes a function `x`, and returns another function where `x` is applied twice to `y`. Please note that in `p`, that `x` is in the function location of the forms, and has been highlighted in the listing to show this.

The use of `x` in both expressions is unfortunately confusing. You can replace any variable in a lambda expression with any other variable, for example `function` - this is called  alpha-conversion - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus - and you can change the name of any named function to something more sensible. So, I've renamed `q` to `square`, the squaring function, and I've renamed `p` to `do-twice`.

```
(define do-twice (lambda (function) (lambda (y) (function (function y)))))
(define square (lambda (x) (* x x)))
```

It then becomes obvious what is happening when you evaluate `do-twice square`.

Answer (score 0):

Francis King's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70244058/16981884) is very clear,
this is just an extended footnote inspired by it.

Replacing identifiers with mnemonic ones (rewriting `q` as `square`) can make it easier to understand code [1]

[Procedures as [first-class] values in Scheme](https://walker.cs.grinnell.edu/courses/151.sp04/readings/procedures-as-values.xhtml) [2] are often introduced with examples using `lambda`:

```
> (define twelve 12)
> (define square (lambda (x) (* x x)))
> (square twelve)
144
>
```

just as the characters `12` in the code above are the representation of a Number,
the characters `(lambda (x) (* x x))` are the representation of a Procedure:
`(number? 12)` => #t, `(procedure? (lambda (x) (* x x)))` => #t

Two further code rewritings may be helpful:
using the "short-form" `define` for procedures, and annotating the definition
with a type signature (argument and result types):

```
> (define (square x) (* x x))  ;; Number -> Number
> (square 3)
9

> (define (do-twice f x)       ;; (X -> X) X -> X
    (f (f x)))
> (do-twice square 3)
81

> (map (lambda (x) (do-twice square x))
    '(1 2 3))
(1 16 81)
>
```

Note that this `do-twice` does not yet correspond to the `p` of the question: making
this do-twice the first argument of map would require:
`(map do-twice (make-list 3 square) '(1 2 3))`

Mapping one list needs a function of one argument, so something has to produce the do-twice of
`(define (do-twice x) (f (f x)))` as its value:

```
> (define (do-twice-with f)    ;; (X -> X) -> (X -> X)
    (define (do-twice x)       ;; X -> X
      (f (f x)))
    do-twice)

> ((do-twice-with square) 3)
81
> (map (do-twice-with square)
    '(1 2 3))
(1 16 81)
>
```

So `do-twice-with` is the function `p` in the question.

`do-twice-with` requires a function argument (X -> X), but X can be any type, so:

```
> (define (repeat s)           ;; String -> String
    (string-append s " " s))

> ((do-twice-with repeat) "buffalo")
"buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo"
```

and `do-twice-with` itself has type (X' -> X') (with X' standing for (X -> X)), so can be
applied to itself:

```
> (((do-twice-with do-twice-with) square) 3)
43046721
  
> (((do-twice-with do-twice-with) repeat) "buffalo")   [3]
"buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo"
```

`((((do-twice-with do-twice-with) do-twice-with) square) 3)` is left as an
exercise for the reader...

[1] "[Naming is perhaps the most powerful abstracting notion we have](https://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Ewilliams/cs357/springer-friedman.pdf)" [Guy L Steele]

[2] https://walker.cs.grinnell.edu/courses/151.sp04/readings/procedures-as-values.xhtml

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo